# Principal components as independent variables

Tags: regression, pca, variable

I have a dataset, which has several environmental variables (lets say 5) measured in 3 different stations over 12 months of the year. I have done the PCA and obtain two principal components (PC1 and 2). I also have average PC scores in each month and station. I then tried to do a linear regression, between a depended variable (X)  in each station and independed PC score of each PC. My problem is I have limited depended variable values in each station than the PC scores. In this situation, could I average principal component scores of PC1 by station and run the model?